# Entity Framework's AddObject seems to be causing significant performance issues, how to resolve?

Tags: entity-framework, azure, entity-framework-6

I am using EF6, and POCOs. I have a performance problem, and have located it to the AddObject line in the following code. All other lines take trivial amounts of time. Using a local database

```
var myOrderList = db.Order.Where(r => r.SupplierId== mySupplier.Id).OrderBy(r => r.Id).ToList(); //Local 5ms Azure 40ms.

foreach (Order myOrder in myOrderList)
{
   var myOrderItem = new OrderItem
   {
       OrderId = myOrder.Id,
       ProductId = product.Id
   };
   db.OrderItem.AddObject(myOrderItem); //Local 20ms Azure 300ms.
}

db.SaveChanges(); //Local 12ms Azure 40ms.
```

So it seems that the AddObject has an inherent performance issue, and particularly exposed to Azure issues.

Thoughts on how I can resolve this AddObject performance issue? Not sure why this is happening.

Thanks.

Edit1

In Azure I am using Azure Websites (Medium) against SQL Azure (Web Edition). My local(dev) setup is made up of IIS and SQL Server 2008 SP2 on WIndows 7 on the same machine.

Comment: What are you writing to in Azure? Azure SQL Database or SQL Server on a VM? If you're using Azure SQL Database you probably need to increase the level at which you are running (Standard or Premium with performance goals setup).

Comment: @SimonW, See Edit1 for setup

Comment: @SimonW, See Edit1 for setup. The Standard and especially premium data tiers are a lot more expensive, and not really a solution to potential inefficiency within EF. One option I am considering is to replace the code with MicroORM code such as Simple.Data which is much more efficient and operates at near ADO.NET speed, or as Edgar states to use ExecuteSqlCommand. I think the AddObject is doing alot of background work such as tracking.... but when this AddObject is in a loop, it adds up very quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem with adding lots of items to MS SQL Server. I ended up using ExecuteSqlCommand which was a lot faster.
But this just adds the data to the database and not to your EF Objects – which might or might not be an issue in your case.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.database.executesqlcommand(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: thank you for this. I have a feeling that AddObject is doing alot of background stuff, so your suggestion is sound, in addition to my comments above. However I would love to hear more input on the issue with AddObject from someone. By the way, ExecuteSqlCommand is no issue in my case, I can go direct.

Comment: I ended up using db.ExecuteStoreCommand("INSERT INTO.... which offered a dramatic improvement

Comment: Not sure about the difference between "ExecuteSqlCommand" and "ExecuteStoreCommand"?